# Multiple Indexes or Single One in a comparison between two large tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, comparison, large-data

I'm going to compare two tables on Oracle with about 10 million records in each one.

- `t1` (anumber, bnumber, cdate, ctime, duration)
- `t2` (fcode, anumber, bnumber, mdate, mtime, odate, otime, duration)

Rows in these tables are the information of calls from a number to the other for a specific month (august 2012).

For example `(12345,9876,120821,120000,68)` indicates a call from `anumber=12345` to `bnumber=9876` in `date=2012/08/21` and `time=12:08:21` which lasted for `68 seconds`.

I want to find records that don't exists in one of these tables but exists in the other. My comparison query is like this

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1 
where not exists(select t1.* from table2 t2 
                  where t1.anumber = t2.anumber 
                    and t1.cdate = t2.mdate 
                    and t1.duration = t2.duration);
```

and my questions are:

1. Which kind of indexes is better to use? Multiple index on columns `(anumber,cdate,duration)` or single index on each of them?
2. Considering that the third column is `duration of a call` which could have a wide range, is it worth to create an index on it? doesn't it slower down my query?
3. What is the fastest way to find the differences between these table?
4. Is it better to loop through `dates` and execute my query with `(cdate='A DATE MONTH')` added to the where clause?
5. Compared to the above query how much slower is this one:

   ```
   select t1.* 
   from table1 t1 
   where not exists (select t1.* 
                     from table2 t2
                     where t1.anumber = t2.anumber 
                       and t1.bnumber like '%t2.bnumber%' 
                       and t1.cdate = t2.mdate 
                       and t1.duration = t2.duration);
   ```

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by `which could have a wide range` ? This question is very broad and it appears to be of topic for this site, unless you are expecting only a very short answer without an explanation "why": `1` - composite index on columns of table2, `2`-worth, it doesn't make the query slower, `3` - your query with proper indices, `4`- no, `5`- if an index on all these field exists - it should be slightly faster, but if the index does not contain new 4th field - it might be slower.

Comment: I'd rather use `LEFT JOIN` which will most likely produce `HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER` in your plan. And as soon as you want to compare all rows there is not much to do with index unless your tables has many columns. If there are only 5 columns in each as you described then `FULL TABLE SCAN` is not so bad performance-wise.

Comment: I did an edit on my question, actually tables have a different number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from t1
minus 
select * from t2
```

don't use indexes, you want to scan all 10 million rows in both tables, therefore a TABLE_ACCESS_FULL is rather in this case.

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1 
where (t1.anumber, t1.date, t1.duration) not in (select t2.anumber, t2.date, t2.duration
                  from table2 t2);
```

see the explain, if good then don't creat indexes, or create like this

```
create index idx_anum_dat_dur on table2(anumber, date, duration)
```

query performance depends on the result of which will return, you must to see the explain and try different variants

Answer (score 0):

Your query is equivalient to:

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1 
WHERE t1.bnumber like '%t2.bnumber%' -- << like 'Literal' !!! 
AND NOT EXISTS (
    select * 
    from table2 t2
    where t2.anumber = t1.anumber
    and t2.cdate = t1.mdate 
    and t2.duration = t1.duration
    );
```

(table references inside quotes are *not* expanded! Is this the OP's intention ??? )